# 18.04 thunderbird font on XFCE has floating pixels

Tags: fonts, xfce, thunderbird

[image: strange floating pixels in thunderbird font]

Please see the attached picture.  The font in Thunderbird has strange floating pixels in half of the letters.  This is on XFCE.  Changing the font within Thunderbird->Preferences->Display Fonts&Colors did nothing.  I'm wondering if anyone has any idea how to fix this.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but I had a similar problem and I installed the latest version of Thunderbird (60) and it fixed the problem

Comment: Yeah, that did it. If you answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I installed the latest version of Thunderbird (60) and it fixed the problem.